# How can I attach Powershell.exe to Debugger?

Tags: debugging, powershell, process

I would like to debug powershell.exe with Debugger program.

But I can't attach powershell.exe to Debugger program.

I am guessing that powershell.exe detect debugger's access and deny it.

How can I attach it to debugger?

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Which debugger? Did you start the debugger as admin? You need to attach from the debugger to Powershell, not the other way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using `Set-PSDebug` or `Set-PSBreakpoint` cmdlets

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849697.aspx;

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh849917.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Powershell ISE Editor, it has a built in debugger. Also you can set breakepoints and it knows all Powershell commands.